# How to search thru Google Spread Sheet

Tags: python, google-sheets, gspread, pygsheets

I'm trying to find a value exist in the GSheet. Connection to Google sheet works. I can fetch all the worksheets within the files, but I can't some reason iterable the list of worksheets.
Here is the file looks likes:
[image]
I'm trying to find cell value and then fetch the values within that column.

Sample Code:

```
#Gsheet setup w/ key.json token
scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('gdoc.json',scope)
gc = gspread.authorize(credentials
sheet = gc.open("GSHEET_Search_test")
cell = sheet.find("B02")
print(cell)
```

Getting errors:

Comment: Can I ask you about your question? 1. I cannot understand about `I can't some reason iterable the list of worksheets.`. Can I ask you about the detail of it? 2. Can you provide the detail of `Getting errors:`? 3. Can I ask you about the detail of your goal? By these information, I would like to try to understand about your question.

Comment: sorry for not providing the details, but I was able to iterate over the worksheet index value rather then the list of worksheet was outputed. Thank you

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to iterate over the worksheet index value `worksheet = sheet.get_worksheet(counter)`